# Javascript Menu Jumping from bottom to top instead of Scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, menu, scroll

I am trying to make a menu that sticks to the bottom of the page and then to the top after scrolling. The only problem is that instead of scrolling with the page, the menu stays in the same place and then jumps to the top right at the end.

I am running stellar.js on the site also and I wondered if this was conflicting but I removed the calling javascript and the problem persisted so I put it back.

The site URL is www.percolatedpropaganda.co.uk

I am stumped and any help would be much appreciated!

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var windowH = $(window).height();
   var stickToBot = windowH - $('#menu').outerHeight(true);

    $('#menu').css({'top': stickToBot + 'px'});

   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( scrollVal > stickToBot ) {
            $('#menu').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px'});
        } else {
            $('#menu').css({'position':'absolute','top': stickToBot +'px'});
        }
    });
 });
```

CSS

```
#menu {
    font-size: 85%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Don't you want $('#menu').css({'position':'absolute','top': (scrollVal + stickToBot) +'px'});
The absolute position is the position relative to document, not window.

Comment: Thank you for you reply.
What I was hoping to achieve was the menu bar scrolling smoothly with the content and then sticking to the top. The code above still creates the jumping effect . . .

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( scrollVal > 0 ) {
            $('#menu').css({bottom: '', top :'0px'});
        } else {
            $('#menu').css({top: '', bottom: '0px'});
        }
    });
 });
```

CSS:

```
 #menu {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
 }
```

Check it out: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6N27z/)

**UPDATE:**
If you want the movement to be animated use this instead:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var menu = $('#menu');
   var windowH = $(window).height();
   var stickToBot = windowH - menu.outerHeight(true);
   menu.css('top', stickToBot + 'px');

    $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
       if ( scrollVal > 0 ) {
            menu.stop().animate({top :'0px'});
        } else {
            menu.stop().animate({top: stickToBot + 'px'});
        }
    });
 });
```

CSS:

```
 #menu {
   position: fixed;
 }
```

Have a look: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/g7x34/)

**UPDATE 2:**

If you want it like `cwtchcamping.co.uk`... have a look at this:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var menu = $('#menu');
   var windowH = $(window).height();
   var stickToBot = windowH - menu.outerHeight(true);
   menu.css('top', stickToBot + 'px');

   $(window).scroll(function() {
     var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (scrollVal > stickToBot) {
       menu.css({top: '0px', position: 'fixed'});
     }
     else {
       menu.css({top: stickToBot + 'px', position: 'absolute'});
     }
   });
 });
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w65Xa/)

Comment: Thank you for you reply.
What I was hoping to achieve was the menu bar scrolling smoothly with the content and then sticking to the top. The code above still creates the jumping effect . . .

Comment: Testing it in JSfiddle has helped as I now know that it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the stellar.js interfering.

Comment: Misunderstood your post. Have a look at the updated answer. Is this what you need?

Comment: The result is certainly smoother but it still scrolls out of sync with the content. I was hoping to have something similar to this http://www.cwtchcamping.co.uk/

Comment: You should have said you want it like cwtchcamping.co.uk from the begining :) Have a look at the updated answer and accept it if that's what you're looking for